# How to move from inbox to conversation tab in kotlin/android..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, kotlin

I have written the code for inbox activity and conversation activity but do not understand how to move to conversation tab when the user click on any message in the inbox tab..?
**Note : **My app is an offline SMS app

I have searched a lot but found nothing.Kindly help me how to resolve this issue.

**Inbox Activity**

```
class InBox : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val requestContactSms: Int = 3
    private val requestReceiveSms: Int = 1
    private val requestReadSms: Int = 2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.readsms)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestReadSms)
        } else {
            refreshSmsInbox()

        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestContactSms
            )
        } else {
            refreshSmsInbox()

        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestReceiveSms
            )
        }

    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == requestReadSms && requestCode == requestContactSms) refreshSmsInbox()
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle", "SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun refreshSmsInbox() {
        try {


            val smsList = ArrayList<SmsData>()
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null)
            cursor?.let {
                if (it!!.moveToFirst()) {

                    val nameID = it.getColumnIndex("address")
                    val messageID = it.getColumnIndex("body")
                    val dateID = it.getColumnIndex("date")
                    val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") //Input date formate
                    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a") //Output date formate
                    val formattedDate = formatter.format(parser.parse("2018-12-14T09:55:00"))
                    do {
                        val dateString = it.getString(dateID)
                        // val sms = SmsData(getContactName(this,it.getString(nameID!!.toInt()).toString()),it.getString(messageID),
                        //SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(Date(dateString.toLong()).toString())
                        val sms = SmsData(getContactName(this,it.getString(nameID!!.toInt()).toString()),it.getString(messageID),
                            SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(Date(dateString.toLong()).toString())
                        )
                        smsList.add(sms)
                    } while (it.moveToNext())

                    it.close()
                }
                val adapter = ListAdapter(this, smsList)
                sms_list_view.adapter = adapter
            }
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            if (this != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,ex.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
        @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        fun getContactName(context: Context, phoneNumber: String): String? {
            var contactName: String = phoneNumber
            val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber))
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
            cursor?.let {
                if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                    contactName = it.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
                }
                it.close()
            }
            Log.d("Inbox","contactName $contactName for $phoneNumber")
            return contactName;
        }

}
```

**ListAdapter class**

```
class ListAdapter (val context: Context, val list : ArrayList<SmsData>): BaseAdapter(){
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent,false)

        list[position].senderName?.let{
            view.sender.text = it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
        }

        view.sms_sender.text = list[position].senderName

        view.sms_message.text = list[position].message

        val date: Date = Date(list[position].date)
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
        view.sms_date.text = dateFormat.format(date)

        return  view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return list[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return list.size
    }
}
```

**Conversation Activity**

```
private const val TAG = "MainActivity1"

class MainActivity1 :AppCompatActivity(){

    private val requestReceiveSms: Int = 1
    private val requestSendSms: Int = 2
    private var mMessageRecycler: RecyclerView? = null
    private var mMessageAdapter: MessageAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

          seupRecycler()



        btnSend.setOnClickListener {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                    requestSendSms
                )
            } else {
                SendSms()
            }
        }

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS),
                requestReceiveSms)
        }
    }

    private fun seupRecycler() {
        mMessageRecycler = this.reyclerview_message_list as RecyclerView
        mMessageAdapter = MessageAdapter(this)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        layoutManager.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
                                                grantResults: IntArray) {
            if(requestCode == requestSendSms)SendSms()
        }

        private fun SendSms() {

            val str_addtes = address.text.toString();
            val str_message = txtMessage.text.toString();

            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(str_addtes,null,str_message,null,null)

            Toast.makeText(this,"SMS Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()



        }
}
```

**Inbox XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView

            android:id="@+id/sms_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Single contact Layout XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sender"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:textColor="#F5F0F1"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/click"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_sender"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Android Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.msgPractice.practice">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".InBox">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity1"></activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Expected:**

Move to conversation tab when user click on any message in inbox tab.

**Actual:**

Nothing happens on clicking.

Comment: I don't see any onItemClick listener assigned to the listview

Comment: READ SMS permission requires approval from google according to their new policies.. Anyway coming to the point, in the recyclerview of your inbox activity give itemview click listener and redirect it conversation activity.

Comment: There is no recyclerview in inbox activity

Comment: @parohy how to attach onItemClick listener to the listview

Comment: @sanjeev there is only listview in the inbox activity

Comment: Kindly tell me how to do this..?

Comment: @Aisha Okay so the list view needs to implement `onClickListener` for the layout.. Just define the main layout id you have used for list item and set on click to it.

Comment: @sanjeev can you show me on the code..?

Comment: the thing I have understand is this: `sms_list_view.setOnCLicklistener{ val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity1::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)}`

Comment: `sms_list_view` is the id of the listView . But there is another layout I have which is for the single contact.

Comment: @sanjeev should I use listView id which is for the whole inbox view or give id of the other layout for the single contact..?

Comment: @sanjeev kindly guide me..

Comment: Where is the adapter that you are setting to the listview? nope don't use for the whole listview..

Comment: I did not post it but I have created an dapter for the inbox with the name of ListAdapter

Comment: @sanjeev I have modified my code now..You can see the adapter class for inbox Activity

Comment: @sanjeev kindly sir tell me what I do now...??

Comment: In rowLayout take the outer layout id and set `OnClickListener` in `getView` of ListAdapter class..

Comment: @sanjeev ok I will try this method and let you know

Comment: @sanjeev I have tried but there is an Intent method error along with  startActivity error..

Comment: `view.clickable.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity1::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)
        }`

Comment: This is the code which I have included..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call startActivity in your adaptor class

```
class ListAdapter (val context: Context, val list : ArrayList<SmsData>): BaseAdapter(){
@SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "SimpleDateFormat")
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent,false)

    list[position].senderName?.let{
        view.sender.text = it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
    }

    view.sms_sender.text = list[position].senderName

    view.sms_message.text = list[position].message

    val date: Date = Date(list[position].date)
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
    view.sms_date.text = dateFormat.format(date)
    view.clickListener { View -> 
        val intent = MainActivity1.newIntent(context, MainActivity1.class)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }       
    return  view
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return list[position]
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
   return list.size
}}
```